# Spring Security custom UserDetails : salt issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, salt

I'm trying to make an authentication form in my web app. With a custom UserDetailsService + UserDetails.

It almost works. It works when i'm trying to log with an user and a password which is hard-coded in my databases. But it doesn't work when I'm trying to log with an user who have a crypted (Bcrypt) password...

I identified the part of code which is an issue (it's a class provide by Spring) :

```
public class DaoAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

    // [...]

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        Object salt = null;

        /* ISSUE : saltSource is null */
        if (this.saltSource != null) {
            /* ISSUE : Moreover, my class UserDetailsImpl which implement UserDetails has no salt attribute */
            salt = this.saltSource.getSalt(userDetails);
        }

        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");

            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials",
                    "Bad credentials"));
        }

        String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        /* ISSUE : Has salt is null, authentication with crypted password doesn't work */
        if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(userDetails.getPassword(),
                presentedPassword, salt)) {
            logger.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");

            throw new BadCredentialsException(messages.getMessage(
                    "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials",
                    "Bad credentials"));
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

There is no salt in this code. So, when salt is null, it compare the crypted databases password with a hard-coded browser password :/.

Do you have an idea ? Thx.

Comment: I have the same issue, isPasswordValid( hashedPw, clearPw, null) keep returning false while I am completly sure of the clearPw used for both, insert and auth. Did you solve this ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I don't have my code on my computer but if I have a good memory, I modifed the method in order to return true in any case. (I create a "salt" field in my class). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Salt is some random data added to the password to generate a unique hash for better security purposes ([What is Salt](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/can-you-help-me-understand-what-a-cryptographic-salt-is)).

```
if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(userDetails.getPassword(),
            presentedPassword, salt))
```

**isPasswordValid** method validates a specified "raw" (presentedPassword) password against an encoded password (userDetails.getPassword()).

The encoded password should have previously been generated by encodePassword(String, Object). This method will encode the rawPass (using the optional salt), and then compared it with the presented encPass.

This means that the salt is optional, so it can be null.

In your case if salt is null should not cause any problem, if you are not using salt while generating the encoded password. Just make sure that, while generating and saving the password you are using Spring security Password encoding api's (PasswordEncoder, BCryptPasswordEncoder etc..) and userDetails.getPassword() returns the encrypted password.

Also note if you are implementing the UserDetails interface in any of your class the auto generated getPassword method in eclipse returns null.